# Upgrade Alfresco from 5.0.c to 5.0.d

Tags: maven, alfresco

I got the error shown below §from maven test state when I updated properties "alfresco.version" to 5.0.d

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>       ...
>   Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03240001 Schema auto-update failed
>       ...
>   Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03240000 Script [ classpath:alfresco/dbscripts/upgrade/4.2/${db.script.dialect}/migrate-locale-multilingual.sql ] can't be found for class org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
>       at org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap.getScriptInputStream(SchemaBootstrap.java:1205)
>       at org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap.executeScriptUrl(SchemaBootstrap.java:1116)
>       at org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap.checkSchemaPatchScripts(SchemaBootstrap.java:1108)
>       at org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap.updateSchema(SchemaBootstrap.java:973)
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using the wrong maven sdk version, as apparently you were on a 4.2.x earlier before (and I guess maven sdk 1.1.1). You need to switch to maven 2.0.0.

Here: [Alfresco Maven Compatibility Matrix](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/alfresco-sdk-compatibility.html) you'll find a more detailed table of supported versions.

Comment: I'm currently using Alfresco SDK 2.0 but I also don't know why it tried to call upgrade script of version 4.2.

Comment: Could you give a little mode details about your environment? OS, DB, etc. Did you restored a database backup or did you started from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely use Alfresco Maven SDK 2.0 and moreover you have to check this [Alfresco Maven SDK tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html) by Jeff Potts.

You're likely using version 1.1.1 of the SDK, in fact in the [understanding the project structure](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html#understanding-the-project-structure) section of this tutorial you will find this passage:

> For example, version 1.1.1 of the archetype assumes you are working
>   with Alfresco Community Edition 4.2.e.

This tutorial will explain you clearly most of the aspects related to Maven SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `alf_data_dev` directory and and do `mvn clean install`.It should resolve your issue if you are developing alfresco application.In case of any other scenario like upgrading it in production environment.This issue will not be there, as it(production) is not using h2 database.